# Changing page number location in a landscape page

Tags: microsoft-word, page-numbers, landscape, microsoft-word-2019

I currently have a document with both portrait and landscape pages. I have managed to rotate the pages using section breaks and have separated each section's header and footer from the previous and next section so that edits in one section, do not change the others. My struggle is in changing the location of my page numbers on a landscape page to where page numbers would be on a portrait page (short side of the page). The numbers would also need to be rotated so that if the pages are printed and bound, all the page numbers would be in the same location.

I have read multiple tutorials online, however, they are for Ms Word 2011 or earlier and some of the buttons that they tell me to press are just non-existent in my word version (Ms Word 2019, version 16.30).

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

### The concepts of how to do this have not changed since Word 5.0 on the Mac (1992).

Location of some controls have changed. So, the tutorials you have found should be instructive and if read should show you the answer. Here is the one I go to: [How to put a portrait page number on a landscape page](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/Formatting/LandscapeSection.htm) by MVPs Bill Coan, Suzanne Barnhill, and Dave Rado. That page is for the Windows versions, but again, the concepts are the same.

I assume that you have already created the landscape section and have disabled different first page and link to previous in the header and footer for that section. I assume that you already have the portrait section to follow and likewise disabled the link to previous and different first page settings in that section.

1. Return to the landscape section.
2. Go into the header or footer for editing.
3. Create a Table, [Text Box or Frame](http://addbalance.com/word/frames_textboxes.htm) where you want your page number
   (without any borders).
4. Double-click in that and insert a PAGE field. You can do this by
   typing the word "Page", selecting it, and pressing Cmd+F9. *(On some
   models you will need Fn+Cmd+F9.)* Then F9 or Fn+F9. (The keyboard shortcuts for this are different on the Mac than in the Windows version, although related. Here is a link to my [table of shortcuts dealing with fields](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#Function) in both the Windows and Mac operating systems.
5. If using a table, rotate the text inside the table. If using a
   [TextBox or Frame](http://addbalance.com/word/frames_textboxes.htm), rotate it with the text.

Here is a [link to a demonstration document](http://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#PortraitHeadersAndFootersInLandscapeSections) I prepared a couple of years ago. [Demonstration of Portrait Headers and Footers in Landscape Sections](http://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#PortraitHeadersAndFootersInLandscapeSections). I updated it today for you. It contains one landscape section with portrait-oriented headers and footers using Textboxes and another using Frames. I do not know if the Mac version has rotating shapes with text (the Textboxes) but I am confident that you can use Frames. It has settings for different even and odd headers and footers. Here is my [Recap of Header and Footer Settings in Word](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#Recap_of_Header/Footer_settings).

This is not simple or easy, but it can be done!

See also my longer answer in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1632554/formatting-word-header-and-footer-for-landscape-sections-so-that-they-are-readab/1632622#1632622).

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your response. I tried your suggestion, however I'm a bit lost on step 4. What do you mean by insert a page field? I also tried to follow the steps from the webpage that you linked. However, following their tutorial, I could not rotate the page number. When I double click the page number, it did not allow me to edit it/ treat it like a text box. I really wonder if this is a mac issue.

Comment: I amended the answer. At the end is a link to a demo document I prepared a couple of years ago to help answer a question on another forum. http://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#PortraitHeadersAndFootersInLandscapeSections I updated that demo today to add a landscape section with the headers and footers in portrait mode using Frames. The earlier verision used textboxes (which are also still shown).

Comment: Did you get a chance to review the demo document.

Comment: See also my lengthier answer in this thread: https://superuser.com/questions/1632554/formatting-word-header-and-footer-for-landscape-sections-so-that-they-are-readab/1632622#1632622  -- You can add a page field with Opt+Shift+P.